# FPDF Getting "Incorrect output destination" but the error code showing the correct destination

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to use FPDF and FPDI to edit a PDF and add text to it. I keep getting an "Incorrect output destination" error but the destination is the correct location that I want it to create a file in, why does FPDF not like my output destination?

This is in a laravel project

```
    $pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setSourceFile(public_path('/pdf/higher.pdf'));
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
    $pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');
    $pdf->Output(public_path('/pdf/'),'higher2');
    return $pdf;
```

and the error is:

```
 message: "FPDF error: Incorrect output destination: /home/vagrant/code/project-name/public/pdf/"
```

I've also tried removing the "public_path()" and just setting it to `Output('pdf', 'higher2')` and no good there either.

Furthermore I've also tried changing the name of the output pdf to `higher2.pdf` just in case it wanted to see the extension (but obviously it's having more of a problem with the destination and not the name)

I've even tried changing permissions on this folder to be writable by anyone:

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 ion  staff    160 May 21 05:44 pdf
```

edit: Just to note I see that the method with the public_path() is trying to save to my vagrant folder for some reason, that's part of the reason I'm confused. When I try to save to '/pdf' without public_path(), I get this error:

```
 message: "FPDF error: Incorrect output destination: /pdf/"
```

**edit 2:**

I've also tried this:

```
$pdf->Output('F','/pdf/higher2.pdf');
```

and got the error:

```
message: "file_put_contents(/pdf/higher2.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
```

and also tried the original name of the pdf which definitely exists and got the same error:

```
$pdf->Output('F','/pdf/higher.pdf');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should never overwrite the file you are reading from!

The signature of the `Output()` method is:

```
string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
```

The `$dest` parameter is defined as:

> Destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:
>
> ```
> I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
> D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
> F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
> S: return the document as a string.
> ```
>
> The default value is I.

So your code:

```
$pdf->Output(public_path('/pdf/'),'higher2');
```

makes absolutely no sense. I guess you want to save the resulting PDF to the path in the public area with the name `higher2.pdf`. So your code should look like:

```
$pdf->Output('F', public_path('/pdf/higher2.pdf'));
```

PS: [You cannot edit a PDF with FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82)!

Comment: aha, adding the public path in that way worked! For some reason it would save to the root file if I set it to ``Output('F', '/higher2.pdf')`` but wouldn't work if I set it to ``Output('F', '/pdf/higher2.pdf') Thank you! As for editing I just meant I'm adding text over it using FPDI

Comment: You should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) about relative and absolute paths ;-) You're also welcome to mark my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks! I am using mpdf and "Destination" is a directory in my mind. Not the output type. Thanks to your answer I now know that "destination" is ambiguous and the output type.

Comment: I think this changed in a newer version of tFPDF. In an older version, there the path was the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The [Output()](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) method requires the first parameter to be the destination and the 2nd parameter the filename.

**From the documentation:**

> F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).

**Try this:**

```
$filename="/pdf/higher2.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Comment: So I've tried that as well and for some reason it works if I make the filename ``"/higher2.pdf"`` but not if I try to put it into my ``/pdf`` folder, any idea why?

Comment: @Maribov does the folder `pdf` exists?

Comment: "[...]the first parameter to be the destination and the 2nd parameter the filename." but why the parameters in the code example are interchanged?

Comment: The folder pdf does exist within the same folder that it saves to if I leave it as ``"/filename.pdf"``

Answer (score 0):

For the `FPDF` package, the syntax `$pdf->Output('F','/pdf/higher2.pdf');` is wrong and you need to adjust your call as Jan Slabon explained.

However, if you want to support UTF-8 characters, then you need the [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) package, which is also supported by the setasign vendor:

```
$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Tfpdf\Fpdi();
```

For this package you can store the output like this:

```
$pdf->Output('/pdf/higher2.pdf');
```